# how do you download an image in the form of bytes?

Tags: python-3.x

I mean I don't want the file to be downloaded onto the hdd, just the string has to be returned in form of bytes so that it can later be passed to some other function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
url = 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTY5MTY3NjgxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDExMTQyMw@@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,987_AL_.jpg'
import requests
# Return data as a string
output = requests.get(url).text

# Return data as bytes
output = requests.get(url).content
```

You could also use urlib or urlib2.

Comment: I know you shouldn't respond with Thanks but i cant help but thank you!